# A wave function normalized for a given time $t=0$ is normalized for every time $t \gt 0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

Given $\Psi(x,t)$ a wave function such that

$$1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Psi^{*}(x,0)\Psi(x,0)dx$$

Prove that $\Psi(x,t)$ is normalized for every $t \gt 0$.

My approach on this has been the following:

Looking at the LHS, we see that it's a function of time ($\phi(t)$ such that $\phi(1)=0$) as the position gets determined with the integration limits. Then, by proving that $\frac{d\phi}{dt}=0$ ist proven that the function is normalized as the integral remains 1 $\forall t\geq 0$.

The part where I get stuck is on how does the RHS behave when you derive in terms of t. As the integration limits are $\pm \infty$ can you use Leibniz's rule and do

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Psi^{*}(x,t)\Psi(x,t)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} [\Psi^{*}(x,t)\Psi(x,t)] dx$$

If so, how can you follow from there? If not, how can you prove this?

Comment: Use the product rule. That gives you the time derivatives of $\Psi$ and $\Psi^*$. Then use Schrodingers equation (or it’s conjugate) to replace $\partial_t\Psi$

Comment: You could also start from knowing that $\psi(x,t) = U(t,0)\psi(x,0)$ with $U(t,0) = \exp{(-\frac{i}{\hbar} H\cdot t)}$

Comment: @JahanClaes. But there u assume that the derivative of an integral is equal to the integral of the derivative. How can you prove that?

Comment: I think you already assumed that when you moved the $\partial /\partial t$ under the integral sign. I'm just saying that once you've moved the derivative under the integral sign, you should keep going: Use the product rule to simplify the derivative, use Schrodinger's equation to rewrite derivatives, etc.

Comment: @Lie you have assumed a time independent Hamiltonian, and that's not really necessary for normality at all times

Comment: Kindly see ow the wave function is written for both position and time part. And then if you use the normalization condition, then the two exponential of each /psi get cancelled up and you get the same expression above you have written.

Comment: Temporal evolution is unitary, which means that it preserves the norm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_(physics)

Comment: @Quillo please post answers as answers, not as comments